# Back Button (activity) Return To Fragment

Tags: android

I have a class that `extends FragmentActivity`

That accesses fragments with the following:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Fragment fragment=null;
    if (arg0 == 0) {
        fragment = new Fragment_01_Rooms();
    }
    if (arg0 == 1) {
        fragment = new Fragment_02_Contacts();
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Now the Fragment called is `public class Fragment_02_Contacts extends Fragment`

Which call another class via intent with the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityChatPrivate.class);
intent.putExtra("valueCONTACT", contactSelected);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now this class called has `public class ActivityChatPrivate extends FragmentActivity`

On this class I am trying to return back to `Fragment_02_Contacts` via the back button. HOW DO I DO THAT WITH

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    //some_code_here to return back to Fragment_02_Contacts 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityChatPrivate.class);
intent.putExtra("valueCONTACT", contactSelected);
intent.putExtra("Fragment", "Fragment2");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your `public class ActivityChatPrivate`

```
String returnToFragment = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fragment");
```

In your `onBackPressed`

```
switch(returnToFragment){
  case "Fragment2"
  Fragment_02_Contacts fragment2 = new Fragment_02_Contacts(); 
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
  transaction.commit(); 
break;
}
```

Comment: " //call your fragment here. "

How do I call Fragment_02_Contacts without calling first the FragmentMain class?